# Disable Button by Node.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i need to Disable a Button using Node.js and Express. My code looks like this.

```
    // ITEM SECTION =========================
app.get('/item/:id', function(req, res) {

    Listing.findOne({'_id': req.params.id}, function(err,products){

        res.render('item.ejs', {
            products: products,
            user : req.user

        });
    });
});
```

I want to disable the Button if the user already clicked it and added the Product to his Favorite list or if the User is the owner of this Product.

My Schema:

```
var Listing = mongoose.Schema({

product            : {
    ownerid     : String,
    name        : String,
    desc        : String,
    price       : Number,
    imagename   : String,
    interessteduser :  [ mongoose.ObjectId ]

} });
```

How can i do this? Do i need to grab all "interessteduser" and loop them trough the req.user?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the id of the user in your scheme (user_click_id - property) who click on the button.
And when he came to the page send check his click.

```
app.get('/item-check/:id', function(req, res) {
Listing.find({'user_click_id': {$contains : req.params.id}}, function(err,users){
    res.send({'disable': users.length ?  false: true})   
});
```

});